# Error:Incompatible Pointer (data not passing to another viewcontroller)

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uitableview

i want to pass a data to anotherViewController from TableView.But i don't know how to pass the data.here is my code.

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     PeripheralManager    * objSelectedDevice=[device objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   // [self prepareForSegue:@"TableDetails" sender:objSelectedDevice];
   // detailViewObject.objCurrentDevice=objSelectedDevice;
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue selectedDevice:(PeripheralManager *)pobjSelectedDevice sender:(id)sender
{


    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TableDetails"]) {

        MeBleDetailViewController *detailViewObject=segue.destinationViewController;


        detailViewObject.dataArray=device;

        detailViewObject.title=@"Supported Services";

        detailViewObject.objCurrentDevice=pobjSelectedDevice;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make an instance variable, set it before making the call to `performSegueWithIdentifier:`, and grab its value in `prepareForSegue:`, like this:

In the header:

```
@interface MyViewController {
    //... your ivars ...
    PeripheralManager *selectedManager;
}
//... more stuff ...
@end
```

In the implementation:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // set your ivar
    selectedManager = [device objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TableDetails" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TableDetails"]) {

        MeBleDetailViewController *detailViewObject=segue.destinationViewController;

        detailViewObject.dataArray=device;

        detailViewObject.title=@"Supported Services";

        // read your ivar
        detailViewObject.objCurrentDevice=selectedManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: shows 3 warnings 1)nested push animation... 2)finishing up a navigation....3)unbalanced call...

Comment: @prem I suspect that the errors are coming from some other places.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/83DD02ku check this link this is my code

Comment: @prem Ah, I think I know what's going on: you have that same segue called in the storyboard, right? In this case, remove this line: `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TableDetails" sender:self];`, it is redundant, and it causes the unbalanced warning.

Comment: yup i remove already but table view data not displayed in nextview controller

Comment: @prem Add `NSLog` calls in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and `prepareForSegue`, and see if they are called in the right sequence.

Comment: ok i will add and inform to you

Answer (score 2):

You don't call `prepareForSegue:` in your code; call `performSegueWithIdentifier:` instead and you will have `prepareForSegue:` called for you.

Comment: thanks warning cleared but data not displayed in next ViewController shows 'null'

Comment: Now two data loading to the viewcontroller(unbalanced)

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what "two data" means.

Comment: shows 3 warnings 1)nested push animation... 2)finishing up a navigation....3)unbalanced call...